# Implement chat functionality like words with friends on ios

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, facebook-chat

I want to add chat functionality to an iOS app similar to what Words With Friends has. Are there any libraries that I can piggy back on or do I need to write it from scratch?

I got a couple of ideas, but all seem expensive:
- Build simple chat client server from scratch
- Host XMPP server and build XMPP functionality into client
- Piggyback on Google Talk or Facebook Chat
-- Facebook Chat XMPP protocol doesn't support group chat which I need
-- Not enough people use google

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you will have to write it from scratch.  I've written an group chat in the app store and I suggest XMPP.